# Facebook and like incrementing together

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a webpage where i want to implement facebook like buttons and share buttons with counters. So i used facebooks own links to generate these buttons for the same url. The problem is that if i like or share the page the counters on the buttons both increment.

For example, i took this random link:
http://forums.asdf.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2523&start=80

I created facebook like and share buttons for it:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.asdf.com%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ff%3D5%26t%3D2523%26start%3D80&width=60&layout=button_count&action=like&size=small&show_faces=false&share=false&height=21&appId" width="60" height="21" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.asdf.com%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ff%3D5%26t%3D2523%26start%3D80&layout=button_count&size=small&mobile_iframe=false&width=68&height=20&appId" width="68" height="20" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Now if i click like both counters on like and share will increment by 1. If i click share the same thing happens. Why arent the counters seperate for each action?

Also jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/vd8ybhee/

Comment: what's the relation to php? there's no "code" to support the question along with a few other tags. You also state: *"if i click like both counters on like and share will increment by 1"* - there's no button anywhere and this seems to be db-related; is it?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_233117017073109

Answer (score 1):

So, it turned out to be normal behaviour. Thanks to CBroe for the link:
developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_23311701707310‌​9